# can I add the Web API folders to an existing project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

Microsoft has a great tutorial here for learning how to build Web API web apps in Visual Studio 2013:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

in it, he shows you how to include the Web API folders and references:

[image: new project dialog]

...is there a way to add these to a previous ASP.NET Webforms project that didnt have that checkbox selected? I'm working on an existing app and want to add Web API functionality to it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes -- there is a tutorial for adding Web API to an existing ASP.NET Webforms project here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

...it doesn't create the Models, Controllers, or App_Start folders, but i added them manually and placed my files from another stand-alone project there. once adjusting the namespaces it all operates properly.